# Convert text formula of a function to a 'real' formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, evaluate

I have in cell A1 the formula `VLOOKUP(A2;Table3[#All];3;FALSE)`. I am struggling to find a way to output the result of the previous formula in B1.

So apparently, you can calculate a text formula using the function "Evaluate" accessible only with VBA like so :

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Then you're able to call it everywhere in your sheet for example, if you put `1+2` in cell A1 and `=Eval(A1)` in cell B1, you get output 3 in B1. So it works fines in this case!

[image]

Works well when you 'evaluate' a simple number too:
[image]

HOWEVER

I found out that Evaluate does not work on texts that include a function (like my above formula of `Vlookup`).

For example if you put `Eval(A1)` in A2 (where 'Eval' is a function itself) then put `=Eval(A2)` in B2, you get "#VALUE".
Same output with above formula.

[image]

Does anybody know how to calculate a text formula like : VLOOKUP(A2;Table3[#All];3;FALSE) (without having to add "=" by hand before the formula) ?

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing all the `;` to `,` within the VLOOKUP.

Comment: Or use SUBSTITUTE to change all the `;` and to `,` and `Eval` the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if documented in a more authoritative place but it seems like you need to use the `,` as the argument separator with `Evaluate`, regardless of your local settings (though I can't test myself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's documented in a more authoritative place - [this link](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-evaluate-tips-and-tricks-to-use-application-evaluate/) does mention it - but `Evaluate` requires a comma as the argument separator in formulas, regardless of your local setting.

As far as the `VLOOKUP` goes, either change the `;` to `,` in the original text, or use `SUBSTITUTE` and `Eval` the result.

Comment: Thank you!! It's weird because I always use `;` in my formulas. I hope they don't decide to change it to `;` in upcoming versions, that would ruin my efforts for scalability!!

Comment: I doubt it will change to be honest. This was also new to me, I would have thought that `Evaluate` would take the local separator into account, but apparently not.

Comment: I've always understood the reasoning behind this is that because VBA is a English/U.S based language, the output would always be the same, independent on locale settings. In the same fashion I for example would not be allowed to use my Dutch equivalents to function names in `Evaluate`. Another clear example of this `en_US` basis would be date formats/recognizion within VBA.

Comment: @JvdV yes that is a thorough explanation and makes sense. The date format is a good point as well.

Comment: Although I can't find any MS Documentation specifically mentioning this behaviour within VBA, [this](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.54.1.45/1/) article does lay down the concept of the VBA code locale (id 1033, being en_US). This MS Visual Studio 2019 [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/globalization-and-localization-of-excel-solutions?view=vs-2019) does also mention the same concept. --> NerdMode OFF =)